# Assembly 8086 addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, addressing-mode

How does `XOR [130][BX][DI], CL` work? (I know what XOR does) I mean how is the effective address of the memory part calculated? Which addressing mode is this?

Comment: Is this what your disassembler shows? Can you please post the opcode in hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `[130]`, not `130`. Are you sure that's correct? I don't know whether (and I don't think) that's possible.

"The Art of Assembly Language" calls this ["Based Indexed Plus Displacement Addressing Mode"](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404s2-03/addr_modes/intel_addr.html#HEADING2-91).

The default segment in this case is `DS` (because you use `BX`), which means your instruction is the same as

```
XOR DS:130[BX][DI], CL
```

The effective address is calculated by taking the segment address and adding `130`, `BX`, and `DI`. So it would be `(DS*10h)+130+BX+DI`.

Comment: It is not 130h, It`s 130 in decimal, so would it be (DS*10h)+82h+BX+DI?